# Hash and encode variable before sending along with request

Tags: scripting, base64, jmeter, sha256

I'm trying to setup JMeter for connecting to a service which requires some hashing be done on some variables before I start and in-between requests.

I've created a User Defined Variable that has the authentication info in plain text.
Before the first HTTP Request is called I need to hash the password using SHA256, encode it using base64 and then convert to uppercase.

I will receive an `auth_token` within a JSON formated response body. Then I  need to do the same `SHA256 -> base64 -> uppercase` chain to that auth_token and from then on it will be used in the request header.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. If you don't implement resource-critical scenarios (load-testing) you can possibly use e.g. [JSR223 Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) / [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) / [JSR223 PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) with a bit of code.

   E.g.

   - Use JSR223 Sampler / PostProcessor / PreProcessor with the following [groovy] code:

   ```
   import java.security.MessageDigest;
   import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
   import org.testng.annotations.Test;

   String [] params = Parameters.split(",");

   String text = params[0];
   MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256");

   md.update(text.getBytes("UTF-8"));
   byte[] digest = md.digest();

   byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(digest);
   String encText = (new String(encoded)).toUpperCase();

   vars.put("encodedValue",encText);
   ```

   - You can re-use this sampler both to hash both password and auth_token - via "Parameters" field in JSR223 Sampler configuration: use e.g. `${password}` variable in the first case, and `auth_token` - in the second.
   - Hashed value you can refer as `${encodedValue}` variable.
2. Similar groovy code used with [__groovy](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) function.
3. [jmeter-plugins](http://jmeter-plugins.org/) set contains `${__MD5(...)}`, `${__base64Encode(...)}`, `${__uppercase(...)}` [functions](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/) but that's not enough for your case (no SHA256 digest).
4. You can also look onto [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to implement the same using your OS (nice if linux) capabilities.

Comment: I was able to streamline it a bit by using

    vars.put("passwordHash", Base64.encodeBase64String(digest).toUpperCase() );

Comment: Only cause I found this now and I needed similar functions. JMeter comes with commons-codec.jar in it's lib path. So you can use that also in the BeanShell :)

Answer (score 1):

There's a new function `__digest`, currently in [nightly builds](https://builds.apache.org/job/JMeter-trunk/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/trunk/dist/)

[image]
In your case to save in encodedValue variable the result of password variable use the following:

```
${__digest(SHA-256,${password},,,encodedValue)}
```

You can download [Custom JMeter Functions](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/Functions/#Custom-JMeter-Functions) plugin to call base 64 encoding function:

```
${__base64Encode(encodedValue, base64Value)}
```

And then call uppercase function:

```
${__uppercase(base64Value, finalValue)}
```

${finalValue} will hold the final value of this operations

Comment: When I run this in jmeter it throw an error trying to set a property on the script file named (the hash value): ${__digest(SHA-256,${password},,,encodedValue)}

Comment: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: baa5f05689d39412e59913c3b514c459d8fa211d696b19322f0ac57334eaf19 for class: Script64